# Find out which application and environment settings symfony task runs with

Tags: php, symfony1

How to find out which application and environment settings my task runs with in symfony 1.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can't, but you can run your task per environment using one of the arguments.
I think this is because of the design of the task. For example, why would you want to run the `generate:module` on just one environment? But obviously you will want to run `cache:clear` on just development environment for example.

To use `cache:clear` in just development environment, you can call it like this:

```
php symfony cache:clear --app="frontend" --env="dev" --type="all"
```

You can see the complete arguments of a task with:

```
php symfony help "task"
```

For example:

```
php symfony help cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

The tasks built by you can also have the following options

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this->addOptions(array(
      new sfCommandOption('app', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_OPTIONAL, 'The application name', null),
      new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_OPTIONAL, 'The environment', null)
    ));

    $this->namespace = 'my';
    $this->name = 'task';
    $this->briefDescription = 'Thats my task';

}

protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
{

    // get the values while executing the task
    $application = $arguments['application'];
    $environment = $arguments['env'];

}
```